# Inserting data into related table with thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have table `user` and table `wallet`, table `wallet` have `userId` so they are connected.

I created controller like this:

```
 @PostMapping("/user/{user_id}/wallets")
 public ResponseEntity<?> createWallet(@PathVariable(value = "user_id") Long user_id, 
 @RequestBody Wallet walletRequest) {

    if (walletRepository.existsByUserIdAndWalletName(user_id, walletRequest.getWalletName())) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(new MessageResponse("You already have wallet with that name, choose another!"));
    }

    Wallet comment = userRepository.findById(user_id).map(tutorial -> {
        walletRequest.setUser(tutorial);
        return walletRepository.save(walletRequest);
    }).orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Not found user with id = " + user_id));

    return new ResponseEntity<>(comment, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

And that works fine when I go in postman and hit API `/api/user/1/wallets` with the appropriate JSON body, I mean wallet is added to user with `ID` 1.

But I dont know how to transform this to consume in Thymeleaf?

This is all stuff that is related to this thing:

First of all API to show new wallet form:

```
  @GetMapping("/showNewWalletForm")
  public String showNewWalletForm(Model model) {
    Wallet wallet = new Wallet();
    model.addAttribute("wallet", wallet);
    return "new_wallet";
}
```

Form inside html:

```
 <form action="#" th:action="@{/api/wallet/saveWallet}" th:object="${wallet}" method="POST">
    <input type="text" th:field="*{walletName}" placeholder="Wallet name" class="form-control mb-4 col-4">

    <input type="text" th:field="*{initialBalance}" placeholder="Enter balance" class="form-control mb-4 col-4">

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info col-2"> Save Wallet</button>
</form>
```

And API to save wallet:

```
  @PostMapping("/saveWallet")
  public String saveWallet(@ModelAttribute("wallet") Wallet wallet) {
    // save employee to database
    walletService.saveWallet(wallet);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

Obviously I'm getting `Column 'user_id' cannot be null` since I didnt set it anywhere as I did in postman.

This is `Wallet` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "wallet")
public class Wallet {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotEmpty(message = "Please, insert a wallet name")
private String walletName;

private double initialBalance;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
@JsonIgnore
private User user;
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the Wallet entity (class)?

Comment: can you also tell whether you have a class that's implemented org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails?

Comment: I updated question, and yes I have a class thats implemented UserDetails

Answer (score 0):

To make this work, you need to be able to fetch the logged-in user and since this is something you will need often, I suggest that you create a Spring managed class.

```
@Component("CurrentUserUtility")  
public class CurrentUserUtility {

public static UserDetailsImpl getCurrentUser() {
    Authentication tAuthentication = getAuthentication();
    if (tAuthentication != null) {          
            return (UserDetailsImpl) getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        
    } else {
        
        return null;
    }
  }
 private static Authentication getAuthentication() {
    return SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
}
}
```

`UserDetailsImpl` is the class implementing the `UserDetails` interface and this class should have a `userId` field (or any other field such as username or email that can be used to uniquely identify the current user).

Now, the only thing you need to do in you controller before saving a new wallet is retrieve the current user using the above utility class.

```
@PostMapping("/saveWallet")
public String saveWallet(@ModelAttribute("wallet") Wallet wallet) {
//user_id shoudn't be null after the next line
wallet.setUser(userRepository.findById(   CurrentUserUtility.getCurrentUser().getUserId() ));
walletService.saveWallet(wallet);
return "redirect:/";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried on different way but will give a shot for your example now. Btw I created this class `CurrentUserUtility ` but I got error `Cannot resolve method 'getAuthentication' in 'CurrentUserUtility'`

Comment: @Stefan Jankovic, sorry, I forgot to add getAuthetication.

Comment: Yes, thats it but still error

Comment: @Stefan Jankovic, what error?

Comment: I changed it, run the program, tried to add new wallet but `Column 'user_id' cannot be null`

Comment: @Stefan Jankovic, can you print some log statements just to make sure you're getting the correct user_id  - System.out.println( wallet.getUser().getId());

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250492/discussion-between-stefan-jankovic-and-dsp-user).